# How to get all the FeatureClasses from IWorkspace?

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class, workspace

I have created a Geodatabase in my SQL Server using ArcCatalog and then I created 5 new FeatureClasses.

Now I want to get all the FeatureClasses in this GDB.

This is my function to get all the FeatureClasses from a workspace:

```
        public static List<ILayer> getLayersFromWokrspace(IWorkspace workspace)
    {
        List<ILayer> layers = new List<ILayer>();
        IFeatureWorkspace fw = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspace; 


        // i tried the both ways to get the datasets in the workspace (i tried the type "esriDatasetType.esriDTAny" too)
        IEnumDataset datasets = workspace.get_Datasets(esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass);
        //IEnumDataset datasets = workspace.Datasets[esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass];


        IDataset dataset = null;
        while ((dataset = datasets.Next()) != null)
        {
            if (dataset.Type == esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass)
            {
                IFeatureClass featureClass = fw.OpenFeatureClass(dataset.Name);
                IFeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayerClass();
                featureLayer.FeatureClass = featureClass;
                ILayer layer = (ILayer)featureLayer;
                layer.Name = dataset.Name;
                layers.Add(layer);
            }
            dataset = datasets.Next();
        }

        return layers;
    }
```

My problem is that I can't get all the FeatureClasses (5), sometimes I get 2 and sometimes only 1 FeatureClass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple things wrong in your loop. First you are calling `dataset = datasets.Next();` at top and bottom of the loop. Right there you are skipping some feature classes.

If your feature classes are nested in a Feature Dataset then you have to iterate through it also.

It's a good idea to call IEnumDataset.Reset() before starting the loop to ensure you are at the start.

Lastly, it's a good idea to release the com reference to each dataset before assigning it to a new one. You can do that using System.Runtime.InteropServices reference and calling `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dataset);`

Comment: Yeah !!!! the mistake was in my loop !! i just removed the last lane in the loop and it works great, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following , changed to get the datasets::

IEnumDataset datasets = workspace.get_Datasets(esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureDataset);

Answer (score 0):

```
List<IFeatureClass> lstClses = new List<IFeatureClass>();
    try
    {
        IEnumDataset datasets = DTEcommonFUnctions.pWrkSpace_pre.get_Datasets(esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureDataset);
        datasets.Reset();
        IDataset dataset = null;
        while ((dataset = datasets.Next()) != null)
        {
            if (dataset.Type == esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureDataset)
            {
                var subFC = dataset.Subsets;
                IDataset pSubSet = subFC.Next();

                while (pSubSet!=null)
                {
                    if (esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass == pSubSet.Type)
                    {
                        lstClses.Add(pSubSet as IFeatureClass);
                    }
                    pSubSet = subFC.Next();
                }                        
            }
            dataset = datasets.Next();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        throw;
    }
    return lstClses;
```